# Why does HTMLParser miss some tags?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I used HTMLParser to count how many h2 tag in http://www.worldgolf.com/courses/usa/massachusetts/

here is the code:

```
class City2Parser(HTMLParser): 
    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs): 
        if tag == 'h2': 
            print 'h2'

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.worldgolf.com/courses/usa/massachusetts/') 
html = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
parser = City2Parser() 
parser.feed(html.read())
```

it only prints once, why? obviously the page has three h2 tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to implement a bunch of handlers in your `City2Parser` to handle the mess of tags and javascript that HTMLParser doesn't seem to take care of out of the box. Why don't you instead use something like BeautiflSoup:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.worldgolf.com/courses/usa/massachusetts/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
s = soup.findAll('h2')

print len(s)
for t in s:
    print t.text
```

gives:

```
3
Featured Massachusetts Golf Course
Golf Locations
Latest user ratings for Massachusetts golf courses
```

Unless the point is to use HTMLParser.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what happens.

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> import urllib2
>>> class City2Parser(HTMLParser): 
...     def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs): 
...         if tag == 'h2': 
...             print 'h2'
... 
>>> req = urllib2.Request('http://www.worldgolf.com/courses/usa/massachusetts/') 
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
>>> parser = City2Parser() 
>>> parser.feed(html.read())
h2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 109, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 151, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 232, in parse_starttag
    endpos = self.check_for_whole_start_tag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 307, in check_for_whole_start_tag
    self.error("malformed start tag")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 116, in error
    raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos())
HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 249, column 30
```

It's complaining about the invalid HTML `<br style="clear:left;"`. HTMLParser cares about getting valid HTML.

Comment: my system didn't raise any exception.

Comment: @Ace: if it didn't, there's somethin' mighty strange about your setup. It certainly should.

Comment: I updated my HTMLParser.py just now. I tried the previous version, error occurred...

Comment: @Ace: "updated my HTMLParser.py"? Are you not talking of the standard library module [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html)?

Comment: I mean it..I updated it to [link](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3ecddf168f1f/Lib/HTMLParser.py)

Comment: Eek! Using portions from the development repository *without using all of it*, i.e. compiling from scratch, is a Very Bad Idea.